# Validating a field value is unique

Tags: plugin-development, custom-fieldtype

I have a custom field type which I need to be unique. So far I have this:

```
/**
 * Validates the field values is unique
 *
 * @param mixed $value
 *
 * @return true|string|array
 */
public function validate($value)
{
    $existingEntryCount = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry)->total(array(
        $this->model->getAttribute('handle') => $value
    ));

    return ($existingEntryCount) ? $this->model->getAttribute('name') . Craft::t(' must be unique') : true;
}
```

This works in that it returns an error if any entry is found with the value submitted, however I need to restrict the search so that it excludes the current entry from the search query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came up with an answer, but be good to know if there is a better way of doing it:

```
/**
 * Checks if another entry exists with the given reference
 * 
 * @param  string $value The reference to check
 * @return bool
 */
private function referenceExists($value)
{
    $existing = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry)->first(array(
        $this->model->getAttribute('handle') => $value
    ));

    return ($existing && $existing->getAttribute('id') != $this->element->getAttribute('id'));
}

/**
 * Validates the field values is unique
 *
 * @param mixed $value
 * @return true|string|array
 */
public function validate($value)
{
    return ($this->referenceExists($value)) ? $this->model->getAttribute('name') . Craft::t(' must be unique') : true;
}
```

Comment: Am confused now as to whether that referenceExists() method should be in the plugin's service rather than the fieldtype too...

Comment: As of Craft 3.7.x (maybe earlier) the check needs to be slightly adjusted. Now you need to compare the existing entries `id` with the elements `canonicalId`, because under some circumstances you could run into the issue that you compare an entry id with a draft id.

Answer (score 5):

If anybody is interested, I created a simple unique text field plugin that extends the core text field: https://github.com/fuel-digital/Craft-Unique-Text-FieldType.

Comment: So did I (github.com/joshangell/craft-unique-value) but yours looks to be much more bulletproof!

Comment: I'm sure it could be improved - it's pretty bare bones but does the job.

Comment: Thanks Russ - this came up as a requirement in a new project... Thanks for contributing to the community!

Comment: Thank you for this plugin. Is this also compatible with Craft v.3?